# React 18 state update batching

Tags: reactjs, history, react-18

While upgrading from React 17 to React 18 I noticed a bit of unusual behavior with React 18.  After investigating further I think it is caused by the way React 18 batches state updates.

In React 17 I ran the following code from `/letters/compose` in order to trigger functions in a `useEffect` on both `/letters` and `/letters/compose`

```
history.replace(`/letters`);
history.replace(`/letters/compose`);
```

In react 17 running the above functions while the user is on `/letters/compose` basically refreshes the page and triggers two `useEffect` functions.  In React 18 neither of the `useEffect` functions are triggered.

So what exactly is going on with batching here (if that is indeed the issue)? Is the first `history.replace` not running at all?  If I add a different function in between the `history.replace` functions would that change anything?

Comment: Did you try adding something in between those `history.replace()` to prove your point?

Comment: @sm3sher Yes, I can see that the issue comes from those consecutive `history.replace` calls. However, I am not sure if it is a batching issue or something else that was introduced in React 18.